# how to install gparted on live fedora usb?

Tags: partitioning, debian, fedora, gparted

i have recently removed ubuntu and installed debian on my entire hdd.  currently /dev/sda1, the partition debian is on, takes up almost all of /dev/sda, minus 3gb which is a swap partion. 
i would like to dual boot fedora, which i have on a live version on a usb.  however when trying to install fedora, it was giving me a hard time resizing the /dev/sda1 partion so i could complete the install.
i figured i could just boot the live usb of fedora, open gparted, and resize the partions that way.  however, for some reason after 
  sudo apt-get install synaptic;
synaptic is not able to be found on the live fedora... so i did 
  sudo apt-get install gparted;
and similarly i, after seemingly installing both synaptic and gparted, am unable to find either on the live fedora.

i feel like im trying to pull myself up by my boots here, what am i doing wrong

Comment: also it is worth noting; i searched for gparted live in synaptic in debian... it is not there, only gparted.  also, i tried downloading gparted live from the site, but nothing seemed to work there either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora does not use the Debian family package managers, apt-get, aptitude, apt-cache... It has its own package manager called `yum`: you ought to look it up [here](http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=25880). This way you will certainly find [Gparted](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/gparted).

Comment: i see, that explains it all.  and i would never have known this being a previous ubuntu user because ubuntu like debian uses apt-get...  thank you much!